# SparkFun Sound Detector Circuit Analysis

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, audio, spice, preamp

I would like to request some help in analyzing the op-amp circuit used by SparkFun [here](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/sound-detector-hookup-guide?_ga=2.136734774.700073415.1548895755-1904572132.1504049533). I'm particularly interested in the pre-amplifier portion of this design.

The write-up included by SparkFun mentions an arithmetic gain of 100. When I simulate this circuit with LTSpice and provide a 10mV 8kHz AC sine wave signal as the input, the output I am getting is ~0.55V 8kHz sine wave. How can this be? I would expect an output of ~1V 8kHz sine wave.

A screenshot of my spice setup is below, I'm using standard part values from the built-in libraries on LTSpice:

[image: LTSpice Simulation]

Comment: The op amp you are using in your simulation is not the one used by Sparkfun. What happens when you use the correct op amp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP-07 does not work with 3.3V supply. Datasheet shows it can work at 6V supply though.

The SparkFun device datasheet also mentions it needing 3.5V or more. It uses a low voltage op-amp that is said to operate down to 2.7V (the op-amp itself, of course the surrounding circuitry must as well).

Comment: Thank you! Supplying 6V yielded the gain as expected. In terms of doing circuit analysis, can you clarify how this configuration yields 100V/V? It looks like a non-inverting op-amp configuration but R1 does not connect to GND as one would expect in a non-inverting configuration.

Answer (score 3):

A gain of 100 at 8 kHz is a gain-bandwidth product (GBW) of 800,000. The OP-07 has a typical GBW of 500,000, so a typical part will not be able to make the calculated output amplitude.

This is a common problem when using older or low-power amplifiers in audio-ish  applications.  The solution is to use an "audio opamp" an opamp with the extra gain and bandwidth needed for full-spectrum audio.  The NE5523/34 also is a fairly old part, but designed from the ground up for low noise, high gain audio applications.

Comment: Is this all that's happening? If I change the input frequency to 3kHz, I'm still only seeing ~0.7V 3kHz sine wave at the output.